# How to set a "must be greater than a value" condition in Rules

Tags: 7, rules

I need to check with the Rules module whether a field is greater than some value. To be more precise, if the size in cm of a product (the field size is created through the [Commerce Physical](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_physical) module) is > than 5000.

How can I do this?  I tried to add a 'Data comparison' but i only get "equals" or "is one of" when i select the comparison operator. I would have expected an "is greater than".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what kind of field you have.  If you have an Integer field, "is greater than" and "is less than" will be available for `Data comparison`.  Perhaps you mistakenly set it to text?  If so, you may need to delete the field and create it again.

Comment: You are right that's the problem, i thought that by selecting `line-item:commerce-product:field-product-dimensions` i was referring to the measurement of the object (Weight * Height * Lenght) but i don't think that's the case. I need to calculate that by hand, any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't.  You'll have better luck asking a new question I think.